# If statetement : I found something strange. Why is my second 'if' is equal to no?

Tags: objective-c, ios, if-statement

If statetement : I found something strange. Why does my second 'if' is equal to no?

```
    int a = bookSettings.tracks.count;
    int b = _currentChapter - 1;
    NSLog(@"a: %d", a);
    NSLog(@"b: %d", b);

    if (a > b) 
        NSLog(@"yes 1");
    else NSLog(@"no 1");        

    if (bookSettings.tracks.count > (_currentChapter -1)) 
        NSLog(@"yes 2");        
    else NSLog(@"no 2");
```

and log

```
a: 27
b: -1
yes 1
no 2
```

Comment: What is the type of `bookSettings.tracks.count`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NSArray's `-count` method returns an `NSUInteger` -- an *unsigned* integer.

Using `bookSettings.tracks.count` in your `if` statement is likely causing both sides of the expression to be cast as `NSUInteger`. Even though `_currentChapter - 1` equals -1, as an unsigned integer it is a *very* large number. So your track count is obviously less than that very large integer, which is why the if statement is yielding "no 2".

Answer (score 2):

I believe that _currentChapter is a NSUInteger.  When you assign it to `b` it becomes a signed integer and is therefore able to use -1.  However, `bookSettings.tracks.count` is a unsigned integer and since `_currentChapter` is an unsigned integer as well, when you subtract 1 from _currentChapter (0, in this case) it actually becomes a very high integer.

Answer (score 1):

you have not mentioned the type of bookSettings.tracks.count and if there is a mismatch between datatypes or object-types , the question comes down to true or false and the if statement will execute accordingly.
There might also be difference between NSInteger ans trivial c int.